# Calculating molecular formulas out of mass of certain elements

Tags: r, loops

For a chemistry project at school I want to calculate molecular masses of all possible combinations of molecular formulas including carbon (1 atom up to 100), oxygen (1 up to 50), hydrogen (1 up to 200), nitrogen (1 up to 20) and sulfur (1 up to 10) and save the results in one vector and the corresponding molecular formula string in another vector. The masses are numeric values: 12, 16, 1, 14 and 32. The strings are "C", "O", "H", "N", "S".

I want to delete molecular formulas that make no sense like C1 O100 H0 N20 S10  from the string and the corresponding mass, too. So to be more specific only leave the ones with a O/C relation between 0 and 1, a H/C relation between 2 and 1, a N/C relation between 0 and 0.2 and a S/C relation between 0 and 0.1.

Is there a easy way to do this, is using a for loop the only way or is there a faster way (maybe arrays?) and how can I take account to the relations of molecules?

Would be vary happy for some ideas or basic code to solve this.

..so @Gregor to disclude the relations of atoms that dont make sense probably will be better before the whole list is created?  @Barker Yes atoms like Nitrogen should go from 0 to max. I am very new to R so when I try a loop I end up with the last value calculated...(reduced amount of dimensions).

```
z=matrix(0,1,5*20*10*2*2)
C=12
O=16
H=1
N=14
S=32

for( u in 1:length(z)) {
 for(i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:20) {
    for(k in 1:10 ) {
     for(l in 0:1) {
       for(m in 0:1){

z[1,u] <- C*i+H*j+O*k+N*l+S*m

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

does anyone know where the mistake is here?

Comment: There seems to be some Chem based assumptions in the logic you've laid out. Is there anyway you could add some 'sample' data or an example of the input and output?

Comment: You'll need to think about the bounds of this problem a little more, I think. As you specify it, the total number of possible molecules in your first main paragraph is about 10 milllion (= 100 * 50 * 200 * 20 * 10) - which is pretty big. You could list all those combinations and then start removing the ones that don't meet your ratio requirements, and then calculate the weights as a last step.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the goal of this.  I am going to start off by assuming that for some elements you want the possible number of atoms to go from 0:N, just because other wise you would have said you wanted carbon to go from 5:100, to make your N/C ratio work out.  Even so, not all molecules that fit your description are possible (C1H1) and not all possible molecules are covered (C1O2). The weight function you have doesn't work because it only takes into account the most common isotope of each atom (carbon can weigh 14au). Also, this formula won't tell you anything about isomers.

Answer (score 0):

`expand.grid` is a good place to start in generating combinations. For example, to create a `data.frame` with combinations of H and C you could do this

```
mol = expand.grid(C = 1:3, H = 1:4)
mol
#    C H
# 1  1 1
# 2  2 1
# 3  3 1
# 4  1 2
# 5  2 2
# 6  3 2
# 7  1 3
# 8  2 3
# 9  3 3
# 10 1 4
# 11 2 4
# 12 3 4
```

You can add on the other elements in `expand.grid` as well and also adjust the inputs up to `1:200` or however many you want. If your computer has enough memory, you'll be able to create the 10MM row data frame as specified in your question - though that is pretty big. If you could reduce the total number of combinations to 1MM it will be much easier on your memory.

The next step would be to delete rows that don't meet your ratio criteria. Here's one example, to make sure that the number of H is between 1 and 2 times the number of C:

```
mol = mol[mol$H >= mol$C & mol$H <= 2 * mol$C, ]
mol
#    C H
# 1  1 1
# 4  1 2
# 5  2 2
# 8  2 3
# 9  3 3
# 11 2 4
# 12 3 4
```

Repeat steps like that for all your conditions.

Finally you can calculate the weights and put it in a new column:

```
mol$weight = with(mol, C * 12 + H * 1)
mol
#    C H weight
# 1  1 1     13
# 4  1 2     14
# 5  2 2     26
# 8  2 3     27
# 9  3 3     39
# 11 2 4     28
# 12 3 4     40
```

You could use matrix multiplication for the weight calculation, but there's no need with a small number of possible elements. If you had 20 or more possible input elements it would make sense to do it that way.

Bonus! Formulas can be created with `paste` or `paste0`:

```
mol$formula = paste0("C", mol$C, " H", mol$H)
mol
#    C H weight formula
# 1  1 1     13   C1 H1
# 4  1 2     14   C1 H2
# 5  2 2     26   C2 H2
# 8  2 3     27   C2 H3
# 9  3 3     39   C3 H3
# 11 2 4     28   C2 H4
# 12 3 4     40   C3 H4
```

Of course, most of these still won't make chemical sense - C1 H1 isn't something that would really exist, but maybe you can come up with even smarter conditions to get rid of more of the impossibilities!